# JVM verifierification -when is it performed?

Tags: java, jvm

I would like to know in what situations exactly would the verifier in JVM kick in and check the class. I know one such instance is when you load the class, but sometimes class is loaded and later on verified. That's why I want to know precisely when that happens.

Comment: Verification is an inherent part of loading. You cannot have a class loaded but not verified.

Comment: What does the [JVM Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/index.html) says about it?

Comment: [Here's what it says :)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.10)

Comment: well, while verifying class A, we can load class B. B is not verified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spec (§4.10) says the following:

> A Java virtual machine implementation verifies that each class file
>   satisfies the necessary constraints at linking time (§5.4).

§5.4 defines what exactly "linking time" means:

> Linking a class or interface involves verifying and preparing that
>   class or interface, its direct superclass, its direct superinterfaces,
>   and its element type (if it is an array type), if necessary.
>   Resolution of symbolic references in the class or interface is an
>   optional part of linking.
>
> This specification allows an implementation flexibility as to when
>   linking activities (and, because of recursion, loading) take place,
>   provided that all of the following properties are maintained:
>
> ```
> A class or interface is completely loaded before it is linked.
>
> A class or interface is completely verified and prepared before it is initialized.
>
> Errors detected during linkage are thrown at a point in the program where some action is taken by the program that might, directly
> ```
>
> or indirectly, require linkage to the class or interface involved in
>   the error.
>
> For example, a Java virtual machine implementation may choose to
>   resolve each symbolic reference in a class or interface individually
>   when it is used ("lazy" or "late" resolution), or to resolve them all
>   at once when the class is being verified ("eager" or "static"
>   resolution). This means that the resolution process may continue, in
>   some implementations, after a class or interface has been initialized.
>   Whichever strategy is followed, any error detected during resolution
>   must be thrown at a point in the program that (directly or indirectly)
>   uses a symbolic reference to the class or interface.

Note as a matter of fact at least Hotspot is doing lazy initialization as described (and I'd be extremely surprised if JRockit and co did otherwise).

Source:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.10

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.4