# Indicating when the JVM Verifier Verifies classes

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode

When running a java program using the java command you can specify the verbose option with -verbose which allows you to inspect when classes are loaded. For example:

```
java -verbose Test | grep "file:"
[Loaded Test from file:/Users... ]
[Loaded C1 from file:/Users... ]
[Loaded A1 from file:/Users... ]
[Loaded B1 from file:/Users...]
[Loaded C2 from file:/Users...]
```

Is there a way to get an indication of when the verification stage happens? Verification of a class doesn't necessarily follow directly after loading it. For example something like this would be ideal:

```
java -verbose Test | grep "file:"
[Loaded Test from file:/Users... ]
[Loaded C1 from file:/Users... ]
[Loaded A1 from file:/Users... ]
[Loaded B1 from file:/Users...]
[Verified C1]
[Loaded C2 from file:/Users...]
[Verified C2]
```

etc

To ward of those "You dont need this", "Why would you want to do this" answers. Its just out of pure interest and is still worthy of a question.

Comment: What is with [all the](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10562876/responsibilities-of-jvm-bytecode-verifier) verifier questions [all of a sudden](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10563569/jvm-verifierification-when-is-it-performed)? Is there some quiz somewhere or something?

Comment: It runs when the class is loaded and eligible for use, during the linking process. The JVM spec does not specify when verification takes place, but it *must* take place before a class is initialized. AFAIK there's no trivial way to examine this step in a cross-platform way.

Comment: What about in a non cross-platform way? I have access to windows linux and osx

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I did not realise he had posted something similar. He is on the same course as me and we have an upcoming exam on the implementation of object oriented programming languages. That said this is more out of curiosity as there are lots of interesting edge cases and it would be good to have a concrete "Verifier verified class C"

Comment: If you really need to, you can modify the source to add a hook and then recompile. Though obviously it won't be official Java any more without the TCK, but it could be useful for personal testing.

Comment: @Antimony I will investigate this and post it as a response. Seems like the only way to do such a thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Antimony suggested, to see when classes are verified one needs to modify the source of the JVM being used before recompiling.

Oracles HotSpot vm source already has numerous logging lines to indicate different stages of verification and they can be enabled by changing

```
ClassVerifier::_verify_verbose;
```

to true in

```
/openjdk/hotspot/src/share/vm/classfile/verifier.cpp
```